# Laravel many to many relation attach to multiple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have many to many relation with pivot table. I know that I can use detach, attach and sync on a model , but is there a way to do this for multiple models with one call ?

For example I have Category and Product models and I want to assign same categories to multiple products.

Comment: Are you searching about polymorphic-many-too--many https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations ?

Comment: Can we see what the models look like